# Cannot find module '@angular/router/src/utils/collection'

Tags: angular, ng-build

I am a newbie to Angular (2 months experience).  I inherited an Angular project using version 6 and Creative Tim template.  I updated the @angular/cli from version 6 to 8.3.6.  The CLI was updated successfully according to the "ng update" command.  However, when I execute the "ng serve -o", I received all kind of errors.

I am not sure what I am missing that keeps my application from building successfully.  Can you help?

I have tried "ng update -all --force" to make sure all the dependencies are up-to-date.

Here is my updated package.json

```
{
  "name": "aac-bc-webui",
  "version": "0.2.5",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -o --base-href /BusinessContinuity/",
    "build": "ng build --base-href /BusinessContinuity/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@adactive/bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.8.2",
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.6",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.8",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "@ngui/map": "0.30.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.37.7",
    "ajv": "6.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.13.11",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "0.7.1",
    "chart.js": "2.8.0",
    "chartist": "0.11.4",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "0.5.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "0.7.4",
    "core-js": "3.2.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.18",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-colreorder": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-bs4": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns": "^3.2.6",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4": "^3.2.6",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4": "^3.1.5",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup-bs4": "^1.0.3",
    "datatables.net-scroller-bs4": "^2.0.0",
    "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.3.0",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.10.1",
    "ionicons": "^4.6.3",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jvectormap": "2.0.4",
    "jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.0.0",
    "nouislider": "14.0.2",
    "npm": "^6.11.3",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.3",
    "sweetalert2": "8.17.6",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "1.2.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.8",
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.4.1",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "12.7.8",
    "codelyzer": "5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "8.4.1",
    "tslint": "5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/paper-dashboard.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/assets/scss/paper-dashboard.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

  &::-moz-placeholder {@content; } // Firefox
 ^
      Top-level selectors may not contain the parent selector "&".
   ╷
25 │   &::-moz-placeholder {@content; } // Firefox
   │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  src\assets\scss\paper-dashboard\mixins\_inputs.scss 25:3  placeholder()
  src\assets\scss\paper-dashboard\_inputs.scss 1:1          @import
  stdin 40:9                                                root stylesheet
      in C:\LocalDev\Repo\AAC.BC.WebUI\src\assets\scss\paper-dashboard\mixins\_inputs.scss (line 25, column 3)
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.6.3 was found instead.
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your question I think. The error message show that your scss is wrong, you can change it to `*::-moz-placeholder {@content; } // Firefox` of wrap it inside `* {}` block

Comment: Thank you. I am so new to Angular that sometimes I do not know what the error message is trying to tell me.

Comment: No worry, practice it more and more then you will know what message they're trying to bring to you.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 8 needs TypeScript ver 3.4 or above. Also, from your post, it is not clear when this error occurs. Is this error occurs using npm install or compile the projects?

Comment: I received the error when I run "ng build" or "ng serve". I rolled the local CLI back to version 6.0.3 and it built. I will do more research on updating CLI.